# How to change the background color of the box in Tkinter with an action

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import platform
import subprocess
from tkinter import *

    ###IPs to use
iptoscan = {
  'test': '8.8.8.8',
  'test 2' : '7.7.7.7',
  'test 3' : '1.1.1.1'
}


    ###Ping function
def ping(ipAddr: object, timeout: object = 100) -> object:
      if platform.system().lower() == 'windows':
          numFlag = '-n'
      else:
          numFlag = '-c'
      global completedPing
      completedPing = subprocess.run(['ping', numFlag, '1', '-w', str(timeout), ipAddr],
                                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  # Capture standard out
                                  stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)  # Capture standard error
      if completedPing.returncode == 0: # I need this if command to send the IP address and a True command
          pingstatus = "Network Active "  # Active ping response
      else:                             # I need this to send the IP plus a False command
          pingstatus = "Network Error "  # No ping response
      print(pingstatus + ipAddr)
      return (completedPing.returncode == 0) and (b'TTL=' in completedPing.stdout)

    ###Function to ping from dictionary
def multiping():
  for ips in iptoscan:
      ping(iptoscan[ips])
  if completedPing.returncode == 0:
      return True
  else:
      print("notworking")
```

My question
Instead of using a "ButtonPress" I want to have the boxes change with the result of the ping, true turns green false stays red. So basically as soon as the code runs I want it to ping from the dictionary and if the results are true I want it to change the color of each box.

```
class OneSquare():
  def __init__(self, can, start_x, start_y, size):
      self.can=can
      self.id = self.can.create_rectangle((start_x, start_y,
                start_x+size, start_y+size), fill="red")
      self.can.tag_bind(self.id, "<ButtonPress-1>", self.set_color)

      self.color_change=True

  def set_color(self, event=None):
      self.color_change = not self.color_change
      color="red"
      if not self.color_change:
          color="green"
      self.can.itemconfigure(self.id, fill=color)

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(N, S, E, W))

    #Boxes to display the network status
IP1=OneSquare(canvas, 1, 1, 30)
IP2=OneSquare(canvas, 1, 50, 30)
IP3=OneSquare(canvas, 1, 100, 30)

    #Exit button
Button(root, text="Exit", bg="orange",
     command=root.quit).grid(row=2)

multiping()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little tricky questions because ping requests called from OS may have delays in them when the destination device is unreachable. This will cause  constant tkinter freezes and delays in your program as the loop goes. To avoid such scenarios simplest way is to use threads (which tkinter is not fond of).

You would need to have a separate thread that does these requests constantly and ends when tkinter does. Make sure you're not doing any calls from that thread to your widgets, as that will make unexpected errors and crashes occur.

Here is a simple example which you can apply to your code:

```
import subprocess, time
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread


iptoscan = {                # Your IP list
  'test': '8.8.8.8',
  'test 2' : '7.7.7.7',
  'test 3' : '1.1.1.1'
}

def startPing():
    while root:
        for id in iptoscan:
            process = subprocess.Popen(['ping', iptoscan[id], '-n', '1'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) # This is just for windows OS (the system i'm testing on), -n 1 if for sending only one ping request
            #labels[id][1] = process.stdout.read().split('\r\n')[2]  # for python 2.x
            labels[id][1] = str(process.stdout.read()).split('\\r\\n')[2]
        time.sleep(1)                   # Delay between ping requests

def updateLabels():
    for id in labels:
        if 'time=' in labels[id][1]:    # This could be our trigger for knowing if ping was successful
            labels[id][0].configure(bg = 'green', text = 'IP: ' +iptoscan[id] + ', time: ' + labels[id][1].split('time=')[1].split(' ')[0] )    # I'm updating the names also as you can see
        else:
            labels[id][0].configure(bg = 'dark orange', text = 'IP: ' +iptoscan[id] + ' ' +labels[id][1] )                                      # If the requst fails, display the message
    root.after(100, updateLabels)       # Continue the loop

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x120')

labels = {}                             # We'll store the label widget and ping response in this dictionary
for id in iptoscan:
    label = Label(root, text = 'IP: ' + iptoscan[id] )
    label.pack(side='bottom',pady=10)
    labels[id] = [label, '']            # First element will be the widget and second one the response

Thread(target = startPing).start()      # Starting the thread to perform ping requests

root.after(100, updateLabels)           # Starting to loop the function that will update ping responses to our widgets
root.mainloop()
root = None
```

Comment: What is the syntax so I can change the label 
from 'IP ' to the first portion of the dictionary for example "test"
"Label(root, text = 'IP: ' + iptoscan[id] )"
I want the label to be Name_dic:X.X.X.X

Comment: That would be`Label(root, text = id + ': ' + iptoscan[id] )` but keep in mind that you would need to change it in the `updateLabels` function as well.: `configure(bg = 'green', text = id + ': ' +iptoscan[id] + ... ` and `configure(bg = 'dark orange', text = id + ': ' + ...`

Comment: For the passed week I've been trying to convert this to PyQT5 do you know how if this can be done?